# "The horizontal and vertical transfers" vs. "the horizontal and the vertical transfers"

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles, lists, ellipses, parallelism

> The Horizontal and vertical tranfers in Local Governement

Is this fragment grammatically correct?

Comment: I would not capitalize anything (except ''the'') and add a ''s'' to make ''transfers''.

Answer (score 1):

No,

> The Horizontal and vertical tranfers in Local Governement

is not a grammatically correct sentence.  It lacks a verb of any sort and doesn't conform to any of the forms of 'sentence' in which absence of a verb is acceptable.

Comment: It should be a title of a short article